# How do I achieve responsive linear gradient without changing the positioning units of other elements?

Tags: css, gradient, responsive

What I mean by responsive is that the gradient transition of the background would be always at the height of a select transparent element, because it would be a design feature to have the gradient transition in the background of the transparent element.

If I view this codepen snippet in chrome code inspector and emulate a view in a different resolution, the transition would be below or above the transparent element.

How do I get the transition exactly under the transparent element on all resolutions without changing the positioning unit type of the transparent element?

I tried to use also % for the gradient stop, but it won't be responsive.

I used a heading as a transparent element for the sake of simplicity, but it's a flexbox row actually, just below the website header and above the page content, so changing the positioning units of that row it seems impossible.

```css
h1 {
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 50%;
  font-size: 10vh;
  color: #00000020;
}

div {
  height: 700px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f19585, #f19585 20vh, #f9e314 26vh, #f9e314 60vh, #9a080f 61vh, #9a080f);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

([*codepen*](https://codepen.io/any_formless/pen/exozmZ))

Comment: Well if you want this to be independent of the viewport height, then you probably should not be using the `vh` unit in the first place …?

Comment: I don’t even understand in what aspect exactly you want this to be “responsive”. Does the real situation not have a fixed height container element? Then what would the height be based on instead?

Comment: Vh and % both won't work in a responsive way, so what should I use then?

Comment: Something more suitable for what you want to achieve … so you will need to describe what that actually is first of all.

Comment: _“Vh and % both won't work in a responsive way”_ - but in relation to a completely different “base” … vh is relative to the viewport; percentage lengths in a linear gradient color stop however _“refer to the length of the gradient line between the starting point and ending point, with 0% being at the starting point and 100% being at the ending point. Lengths are measured along the gradient line from the starting point in the direction of the ending point.”_ (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#typedef-color-stop-list)

Comment: I cannot reveal my actual project here, but sticking to the codepen example, is it possible to make that transition be at the height of the transparent element at all resolutions, without changing the positioning unit of the transparent element from px to something else? Without changing anything about the transparent element.